# Entropy of systems of equations with finite solutions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

## Problem Statement

In this setup, there are a finite number of variables $x_1..x_n$ which may take a value in the range $[1, k]$. Some of these variables are unknown while others are unknown though are constrained through a set of inequalities. For instance, suppose there are $n = 5$ and $k = 10$, one such set might be:

$$x_1 = 2$$
$$x_2 \neq x_3$$
$$x_3 \neq x_1$$
$$x_4 \neq x_2$$
$$x_5 = 5$$
$$x_2 \neq x_5$$

Additionally, assume that the each of the values of $x$ were chosen equally likely over the range of possible values and then the inequalities were determined (i.e. maybe the actual solution to the above example was randomly chosen to be $\pmb{x} = [2, 1, 3, 3, 5]$ and then the (in)equalities above were chosen to describe this system (we of course don't know the actual solution of $\pmb{x}$ and are only given the system of equations).

Given a setup like this, is there an efficient way to calculate the total entropy of a system like this? This is a non-trivial problem in my mind since there are a large number of dependent variables in a setup like this thereby complicating trying to use combinatorics.

Edit: I forgot to mention the definition of entropy in this setup. Entropy would be the amount of information needed to describe the system (i.e. the log of the total number of possible configurations of $\pmb{x}$.

## Possible Solution Method

In the example above, each of of the inequalities depends on a maximum of two random variables. Therefore, these inequalities can be easily translated into join probabilities. Using this transformation, this setup can then be described as an optimization problem which can be solved numerically (possibly using Lagrangian Multipliers).

Additionally, we can ignore both $x_1$ as well as $x_5$ since these are already determined.

The function to maximize would therefore be the entropy of all the join probabilities.

For optimization, the units of the logarithm do not matter since it only affects the units of the computed entropy. This optimization is then constrained by both the fact that the probabilities a particular $x$ takes on a value given some other fixed condition must sum to $1$ as well as the additional given constraints.

Luckily, the constraints are obviously linear and while the entropy function is obviously nonlinear, it is convex. Therefore, there are a large number of suitable optimization algorithms which can be used to solve this problem such as gradient descent using Lagrangian Multipliers.

In general, this technique can be extended to arbitrarily complex constraints by using sufficiently broad joint probabilities. For instance, 3-way joint probabilities would need to be used if $x_2 \neq x_3 + x_4$ was a constraint.

Comment: By the entropy of the system, do you mean: Entropy of the distribution assuming you pick uniformly from all valid solutions?

Comment: The entropy could assume any value between 0 and $\max  H$. Do you want to calculate the maximum entropy subject to given constraints? In that case you must solve a Lagrangian multiplier optimization which is not trivial.

Comment: I'm not certain how the entropy could be less than max H, but that is what I'm trying to calculate. Thank you for the starting point!